# Is there are any way of creating stubData with RANDOM VALUES in Sinon instead of using static JSON FORMATE

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sinon

I am writing test cases using SINON to test my APIs in my NODE project, where I'm stubing my DB data.
But instead of getting static data in my stub resolves value, I want to use some kind of randomizer which will generate random string or number for my stubData json.

What I'm doing ==========================:

```
const stubData = {
      name = "XYZ",
      age = 19,
      DOB = "2004-12-08"
}

DBStub = sinon.stub(mongoDB.protype, "findbyId")

DBStub.withargs("2").resolves(stubData)

const res = await request(app)
            .get('/api/data')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200);

const returnedBank = res.body;
expect(returnedBank).toMatchObject({ id: '2', status: 'success' });
```

What I'm Expecting =========================:

```
const stubData = {
      name = Some Randomizer(string),
      age = Some Randomizer(number),
      DOB = Some Randomizer(date)
}

DBStub = sinon.stub(mongoDB.protype, "findbyId")

DBStub.withargs("2").resolves(stubData)

const res = await request(app)
            .get('/api/data')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
            .expect(200);

const returnedBank = res.body;
expect(returnedBank).toMatchObject({ id: '2', status: 'success' });
```

Comment: Sure, you can write a randomizer, or use an existing faker-style library..

Comment: thanks for the answer!
but is there any inbuilt Sinon method which can helps me to do it instead of using faker library.